# Texture marked for update but image is undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, openlayers

I want to use openlayers to create a map, and then use the map's canvas as a parameter to threejs' CanvasTexture to create a texture, but it seems to be a problem, I do n’t know how to solve it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwEwf.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as an image. That way other users can test your code by copying directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create an instance of `THREE.CanvasTexture` with an `undefined` object. Notice that the value of `mapCanvas` is assigned in the `rendercomplete` event listener. I suggest you put your `three.js` related code right after this line:

```
mapCanvas=$('.ol-layer').find("canvas")[0];
```

Comment: OK, thanks, the warning disappeared after I did this, but the map as texture did not appear, do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see this from your code. I suggest you accept the answer/upvote and ask a new question. This time please share your code not as a screenshot but embed it in your post. Or even better, share a live example.